# Setting Focus on DataGridTemplate combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a `DataGrid` that that has a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. In the Template Column I have a `ComboBox`. I would like to set focus on this `combobox` and be able to start typing to see the items in the `ComboBox`. However this is a bit more tricky than expected.

thanks in advance.

**xaml**

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ItemNumber">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Parts,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                              x:Name="CboItems"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Code"
                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PartId}"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                        <ComboBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">

                            </Style>
                        </ComboBox.Style>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Code**

```
private void SelectCorrectComboBox(ShilListItemArgs e)
{
    DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Item);
    var rowIndex= DataGrid.SelectedIndex;
    var row = DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
    var cell = GetCell(DataGrid, row, 3) as DataGridCell;

    if (cell!=null)
    {
        cell.IsEditing = true;
        cell.IsSelected = true;
        var contentpresenter = cell.Content as ContentPresenter;
        if (contentpresenter != null)
        {
            contentpresenter.ApplyTemplate();
            var content = contentpresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("CboItems",contentpresenter);
            var comboBox = content as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
I have tried this as well and cannot get this to work.

```
var edit = (TextBox)myCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myCombo);
```

Comment: A few details about the problem you're having would help.

Comment: It does select the ComboBox, but when I go to start typing it doesn't. it doesn't throw exception. i just doesn't type.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the anwser.

```
private void SelectCorrectComboBox(ShilListItemArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Item);
        var rowIndex= DataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        var row = DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        var cell = GetCell(DataGrid, row, 3) as DataGridCell;

        if (cell!=null)
        {
            cell.IsEditing = true;
            cell.IsSelected = true;
            var contentpresenter = cell.Content as ContentPresenter;
            if (contentpresenter != null)
            {
                contentpresenter.ApplyTemplate();
                var content = contentpresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("CboItems",contentpresenter);
                var comboBox = content as ComboBox;
                if (comboBox != null)
                {
                    comboBox.Template.LoadContent();
                    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    comboBox.Focus();
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        var edit = (TextBox)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox);
                        if (edit!=null)
                        {
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) delegate
                            {
                                SetTextBox(edit);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void SetTextBox(TextBox t)
    {
        t.Focus();
    }
```